# tkinter -button doesn't display the label until whole function(associated with button) is processed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a gui using `tkinter` in `python 2.7`. In the GUI there are buttons which perform functions. The issue is that when the button is clicked, it doesn't display the label until the whole function is finished. Sample code:

```
button4=tk.Button(self,text="MEMORY",height=1,width=20,font=LABEL_FONT,fg=mycolor,bg='light blue',command=lambda: controller.show_frame(memory)) 
button4.place(relx=0.6, rely=.53,width=120, anchor="sw")
```

the funtion associated with button is:

```
def memory(self):
    label = tk.Label(
        self,
        text="Calculating, Please wait...",
        font=text_font,
        fg="white",
        bg=mycolor)
    label.place(relx=.0005, rely=.17)
    f3 = open('filename' ,"r")
    list1= list()
    list2= list()

    # Calculating some values which takes around 5 minutes as the lists are huge
```

here the text "please wait..." is displayed only after 5 minutes, *i.e.* after the calculation. I need the text (label) to be displayed soon after the button is clicked.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Create function for changing label and function for doing what you need to do and when executing call text function before calculation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call update before starting long calculations

```
def memory(self):
    label = tk.Label(
        self,
        text="Calculating, Please wait...",
        font=text_font,
        fg="white",
        bg=mycolor)
    label.place(relx=.0005, rely=.17)
    self.update()
    f3 = open('filename' ,"r")
    list1= list()
    list2= list()

    # Calculating some values which takes around 5 minutes as the lists are huge
```

But you'd better use thread